# Container id not found when using KafkaIO ReadFromKafka in Flink Cluster

Tags: python, apache-beam

I have a Flink cluster (running in minikube) with a worker pool running Python SDK 2.27.0 with pipeline options:

```py
options = PipelineOptions([
        "--runner=FlinkRunner",
        "--flink_version=1.10",
        "--flink_master=localhost:8081",
        "--environment_type=EXTERNAL",
        "--environment_config=localhost:50000",
        "--streaming"
    ])
```

I have the following pipeline:

```py
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        _ = (p
            | 'Create words' >> ReadFromKafka(
                    topics=['vt2l0h0h-test2'],
                    consumer_config={'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092,localhost:9093', 'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'}
                )
            | 'window' >> beam.WindowInto(window.GlobalWindows(), trigger=trigger.Repeatedly(trigger.AfterCount(1)), accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.ACCUMULATING)
            | 'Group' >> beam.GroupBy() # might need to do batching here
            | 'print' >> beam.Map(print)
        )
```

The ReadFromKafka comes from beam's KafkaIO transformation. Regardless of passing an expansion service address, a docker container is downloaded apache/beam_java11_sdk:2.27.0. I had issues with docker on the worker that wouldn't run the pipeline but after adding docker through docker-in-docker (dind image) I got through "docker not found" issues on the worker but now when the container tries to start I get this error indicating that the container could not be started.

```
WARNING:root:Make sure that locally built Python SDK docker image has Python 3.7 interpreter.
ERROR:root:java.lang.IllegalStateException: No container running for id 920a42773fa41d30d1401de8f8a1d5d9e0f314f1c6dc373391257951ca111a48
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "job.py", line 114, in <module>
    run()
  File "job.py", line 109, in run
    | 'print' >> beam.Map(print)
  File "/home/muller/Documents/Repository/flink_cluster/.env_flink/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 583, in __exit__
    self.result.wait_until_finish()
  File "/home/muller/Documents/Repository/flink_cluster/.env_flink/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/portable_runner.py", line 581, in wait_until_finish
    raise self._runtime_exception
RuntimeError: Pipeline BeamApp-muller-0302084536-d89ec2f6_1b9909aa-7d5a-4492-bc06-181634c74f87 failed in state FAILED: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No container running for id 920a42773fa41d30d1401de8f8a1d5d9e0f314f1c6dc373391257951ca111a48
```

I have no idea what is calling this docker container to start in the first place, but what would prevent this container from starting, it starts the image and runs KafkaIO when running on the DirectRunner?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this one out. I don't use a job server but rather use a sidecar in my Kubernetes setup which is fine but then you need to pass the option "--flink_submit_uber_jar". This bundles all artifacts into the jar file uploaded to flink runner.

Comment: I'm trying the same thing. Could you please explain little bit more about your setup? I install docker in `taskmanager` container and trying to run beam_java_sdk container within it. But it's not working out. I'm getting `failed to dial server at localhost:36795` error message in log. Is there any other approach for this?